# dynamically appends tensor to list in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Supposed I have a list of tensorflow tensor, I want to dynamicaly append extra tensor to this list under certain condition. e.g., if the maximum dot product between each tensor in the list and this extra tensor is larger than 0, than this extra tensor is appended to the list. Here is the code:

```
lists = []
for i in xrange(10):
    a = tf.get_variable(name=str(i), shape=[3], dtype=tf.float32)
    lists.append(a)
```

so right now we have a list of 10 tensors, each tensor has shape [3].

```
for j in xrange(11, 30):
    b = tf.get_variable(name=str(j), shape=[3, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
    c = tf.stack(lists)
    e = tf.cond(tf.reduce_max(tf.reshape(lists, shape=[-1]), axis=0)>0.00, lambda: tf.stack(lists.append(tf.reshape(b, [-1]))), lambda: c)
    lists = tf.unstack(e)
```

However this code has several problems, first of all,

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is because `tf.stack(lists.append(tf.reshape(b, [-1])))`, `lists.append(tf.reshape(b, [-1]))` is a 'NoneType'.

Second problem is that even if this part is working, then `lists = tf.unstack(e)` has a bug because `ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, 3)` because `tf.unstack()` can not work on non-inferrable dimensions.

Would you guys please teach me how to implement this function? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have at least two different problems here.

First problem: I don't understand what kind of `reshape` you aree doing. I would use `tensordot` instead. And I would *not* convert the tensor back into a list, if not needed.

For example:

```
c = tf.stack(lists)    # shape [10,3]
for j in range(11, 30):
    b = tf.get_variable(name=str(j), shape=[1, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    d = tf.tensordot(b, c, axes=[1,1])     # shape [1,10]
    c = tf.cond(tf.reduce_max(d) > 0.00, lambda: tf.concat([c, b], 0), lambda: c)  # shape [?,3]
```

Second problem: convert a tensor with non-inferrable dimensions into a list. There are lots of questions and answers about this topics:

http://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow+unstack+can+not+work+on+non-inferrable+dimensions

Hope that helps.